# Angular UI bootstrap Modal is not working with AEM and sightly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, aem, sightly

In my application, I am using Angular UI bootstrap with AEM and having the sightly parameters in the same.

The issue is, when I try to access the sightly parameters inside the `script` tag of UI modal It is not rendenring the sightly parameters.

```
< script type="text/ng-template" id="/view2.tpl" data-sly-include="template.html">
   ${properties.title}
< /script >
```

This specific problem is there with Sightly with AEM and angular. Can anyone suggest how to make a Modal work for Angular+AEM+sightly?

Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [specification](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#228-include), using `data-sly-include` will cause the content of the `<script>` tag to be replaced with the content of the included script.

If you want to use HTL/Sightly templates from `template.html` you should instead write `data-sly-use.tpl="template.html"`

Answer (score 0):

First, for using templates, use the `data-sly-use` instead of `data-sly-include`.

Second, HTL (Sightly) escapes the expressions by default depending on the context where they are used. You can explicitly specify the context using the `context` option as shown below.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/view2.tpl">
    <!--/* Use scriptString if you are using the value as a string */-->
    ${properties.title @ context='scriptString'}
    <!--/* In case you are trying to output an entire function or javascript, 
     there is no context specifically available for that. So, you can use the 
     unsafe option to disable escaping completely */-->
    ${properties.title @ context='unsafe'}
</script>
```

More information on [Display Context can be found here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/expression-language.html#Display%20Context) and information on [Template and Call here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/block-statements.html#template%20&%20call).